# Cannot resolve method 'setTorchMode(java.lang.String, boolean)'

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to create an Android activity which accesses the flashlight/torch of any camera on the device which has one. CameraManager has a method which allows you to turn it on named setTorchMode, which takes a camera ID as a string and a boolean which states true or false for the state of the flashlight. Unfortunately, when I try to use this method it gives me the error

```
Cannot resolve method 'setTorchMode(java.lang.String, boolean)'
```

I have all of these imported

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.*;
```

I added the * later to see if I was just missing the proper class. This is what the method looks like

```
public void turnOnLight(View view) {


        String[] camIDs;
        try {
            camIDs = camMan.getCameraIdList();

            if(camIDs.length > 0) {
                for (String camera : camIDs) {
                    int intCamID = Integer.parseInt(camera);
                    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = camMan.getCameraCharacteristics(camera);
                    boolean flashAvailable = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
                    if(flashAvailable) {
                        camMan.setTorchMode(camera, true); //here is the error
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException camae) {
            camae.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have camMan globally defined and initialized in my init with this line

```
camMan = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
```

Would anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I am getting this error because I am using a third-party SDK which is at api level 22. Unfortunately, setTorchMode() cannot be called below api level 23. To turn on the flashlight, the code I used which worked in this api, although deprecated, is

```
 Camera mCam;
 Camera.Parameters p;
 mCam = Camera.open();
 p = mCam.getParameters();
 p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
 mCam.setParameters(p);
 mPreviewTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
 try {
          mCam.setPreviewTexture(mPreviewTexture);
 } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 mCam.startPreview();
```

To turn off the flashlight, the code looks the same, but using

```
p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
```

instead of

```
p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```